# How to exact the value from a array

Tags: php, arrays

My array structure is

Array

(

```
[customer_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [customer_id] => 123
            )
    )
[menu_item_net_price] => 1700
[menu_item_tax_price] => 4%
[menu_item_gross_price] => 1700
[provider_id] => 123
```

)

I need to get the value of `[customer_id] => 123`. Tell me how can I do that?

Still my problem is not solved so I am posting code:

```
$data['customer_id'] = $this->session->userdata('id');
            $data['menu_item_net_price']= $netPrice;
            $data['menu_item_tax_price']= '4%'; 
            $data['menu_item_gross_price']= $netPrice;
            $data['provider_id']= 123; 
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($data);
            echo '</pre>';
            exit(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just go through your array step by step until you are at the needed property.

```
$arr[ 'id' ][ 0 ][ 'customer_id' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
$array["id"][0]["customer_id"]
```

or if you want to get all customers' ids, use foreach

```
foreach($array["id"] as $index => $data) {
    $customer_id = $data["customer_id"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approach to get the value of customer_id.
1. If you array is dynamic and you are not sure, what will be the key value, you can use [key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) or [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function of php. Then you can retrieve it.

```
array['id'][$key]['customer_id']
```

for multiple keys, you can use foreach loop.

2.If is static array, then you can get it direct.

```
  array['id'][0]['customer_id']
```